# Does the expression "speak volumes" generally have a negative connotation?

Tags: phrase-usage

I get the sense that we tend to use "speak volumes" in a negative way. For example, if I heard "His attendance record spoke volumes for his commitment," in isolation, I'd tend to think his attendance record wasn't great, and we could infer the same about his commitment.

It can definitely be used in a positive sense, as in, "His perfect attendance record and gung-ho attitude spoke volumes about his commitment," but I think those usages are rarer.

I get the sense that this is maybe because we use "speak volumes" for small things that signify a great deal, and it's much easier to signify something negative with a small gesture (or a lack of gesture) than something positive.

Can anyone back up or contradict my impression with data or some authority?

Comment: It all depends on how it's used.

Comment: The above comment speaks volumes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression has no negative or positive connotation in itself, it just depends on usage. Also its origin suggests no specific (positive/negative) connotation:

***[Speak volumes](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/volume) (about/for something/somebody):*** (OLD)

> - to tell you a lot about something/somebody, without the need for words
>
>   - *His achievement speaks volumes for his determination.
>       What you wear speaks volumes about you.*

***[Speak volumes](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/speak+volumes):*** (AHD)

> - Be significant, indicate a great deal, as in That house of theirs speaks volumes about their income.
> - ***Origin:***  This idiom uses volumes in the sense of "the information contained in volumes of books." [c. 1800]

Early usage examples:  (OED)

> - ***1803 M. Wilmot Let. 3 May in Russ. Jrnls. (1934) i. 13*** A sentimental story that speakes Volumes in favour of the Count and his Daughter.
> - ***1810 Shelley Zastrozzi iv. Pr. Wks. 1888 I. 23*** A pause ensued, during which the eyes of Zastrozzi and Matilda spoke volumes to each guilty soul.
> - ***1833 Whittier Abolitionists Pr. Wks. 1889 III. 86*** The late noble example of the eloquent statesman..speaks volumes to his political friends.